# Существует ли историческая связь между приставкой "раз-" и словом "разве"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Приставка РАЗ  имеет значение разделения, распределения, распространения и др., то есть **разделение** можно считать ее обобщенным значением.

Слово "разве" используется:

а)  в вопросительных предложениях для выражения **сомнения**;

б) участвует в образовании составного союза "разве только" (вносит значение **допущения**).

Разделение, сомнение, допущение — какая может быть связь между этими понятиями?

И какова этимология этих слов?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (вариант ответа)

По не очень ясным доказательствам это вроде бы **родственные слова**.

Тогда так:

1) Разделяю, отделяю и исключаю (получается значение ***кроме***).

2) Потом сомневаюсь, возвращаю обратно (тоже в виде исключения) и допускаю (значение **допущения**).

3) А вот как насчет **сомнения**? Но в общем-то подобные действия как раз иллюстрируют сомнение действующего субъекта в правильности выбранного решения.

**Или можно как-то еще всё это объяснить?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Н.М.Шанский утверждает историческую общность РАЗ и РАЗВЕ.

РАЗВЕ. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где оно восходит к общеслав. *orzvě, форме местн. пад. *orzvъ **«часть, половина»,** суф. производному от *ordz > раз (см. разбавить), суф. образованию от той же основы, что др.-инд. árdhas «часть, половина».

Русское *orz- **врозь, в стороны** восходит к инд.-евр. *ord-z, dz >z

https://shansky.lexicography.online/%D1%80/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5

У Даля:

Разве.церк. **развее** стар. предлог или нареч. с родительным пад. *опричь, кроме, окроме, исключая, за исключеньем.* мене, кроме меня. Четыре тысящи, разве жен и детей,  среди нас найдутся охотники. А бояре в том суде не сидят, развее писарей. | нареч. вопросительное: неужли, неужто, или, нешто, будто. Разве ты еще не слышал? Разве  не веришь ему? | Выраженье нерешительности, сомненья. Разве сходить к ней? не сходить ли. Уж разве уступить ему? не лучше ли уступить. Как быть? разве броду попытаться? нешто. | Нареч. условное: ежели, если, буде, коли. Разве за ум возьмется, а то все пропадет. Разве помру, а то кончу словарь свой. ты сыт?

Древние значения были довольно общими, широкими, от них потом образовались переносные. Если **разве** образовалось от **раз**, то в нём значение **врозь** будет главным, это понятно, если вспомнить, что исходное **резать, разить**. Древнерусское сущ. разъ -черта, граница. **Всё связано с разделением**.

Общеславянское значение *orzvъ **«часть, половина» может развить значение сомнения** - это часть чего-то, не всё: Разве сходить в кино? - часть за то, чтобы сходить, а часть - против.

Значение **допущения** тоже близко **в значении условного наречия**: *Разве за ум возьмётся,а то всё, пропадёт*. **Здесь и сомнение, и допущение,** т.е. надежда (если возьмётся за ум, то не пропадёт).

Comment: Насколько я поняла у Шанского и немного у Черных, родственными являются слова разве, разный, врозь. Разить и резать - это другое семейство (у Шанского), а у Черных и эти два слова имеют разное происхождение. остается только ПОЛОВИНА (по Шанскому), отсюда и надо выводить все значения (как бы fifty-fifty).

Comment: Это с современной точки зрения разные семейства, а Вы же спрашивали про историческую общность? Или я чего не понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

[Словарь Фасмера](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%80/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5):

**ра́зве** также в стар. знач. «**кроме**», русск.-цслав. развѣ «**только, кроме**», наряду с др.-русск. розвѣ — то же (Срезн. III, 28, 150), ст.-слав. развѣ πλήν, εἰ μή (Остром., Клоц., Супр.). Форма развѣ является цслав., тогда как розвѣ — исконнорусск Из *orzvě-, вероятно, стар. местн. п. ед. ч. от *orzvъ, производного от *orz- (см. роз-, раз-), ср. *кро́ме, горе́ «вверх»*; см. Вондрак, Vgl. Gr. 2, 294; Мi. ЕW 226; Преобр. II, 175. Неприемлемо сравнение с лит. regì «видишь», вопреки Маценауэру

Получается, что только нечто допускается, кроме всего прочего. Значение разделения сохраняется, допущения тоже.

Comment: Я видела похожую информацию у Шанского и даже Черных, но мало что  из нее не поняла. Черных пишет что этимология здесь очень неясная, но хотя бы разные значения как -нибудь объяснить.